# MySQL Throws NullReferenceException in Finalize... How are you coping with this?

Tags: .net, mysql, database, ado.net, finalizer

I am using MySQL with the .Net connector on 64 bit Windows. For some reason Mysql is throwing a NullReferenceException in Finalize. This is the problem [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,359776,366634) and it seems that its due to a bug described [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/53457). This bug was reported in 6.22, but I am getting the issue with 6.23 too so apparently it is not fixed.

I am using MySQL both with the helper classes, and by instantiating the connection and the Mysqlcommand object.

Does anybody have any idea what part of my code do I need to change to fix this issue? Cause even though this is a bug in Mysql this is not universal because I am not getting the problem in my other projects. MySQL bug report has no details on how to reproduce it either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `Dispose` on the `MySqlConnection` (or wrap it in `using`) then in theory the finalizer should not be called, at least if `MySqlConnection` was implemented properly.

If you are doing that and it's still called you'd have to have a look at the source code and see if it's doing anything useful. If not, you could call `GC.SuppressFinalize()` on it. If it is, you could subclass `MySqlConnection`, override its `Finalize()` method and swallow the exception thrown by the base method. Obviously, both of those approaches are *major hacks* and are only workarounds, not fixes.

Comment: You could have an idea there. I am using the MySQLHelper in places which is definitely not calling dispose. Let me replace all the locations with MySQLHelper and see if that helps.

Comment: Getting rid of MySQLHelper helped!!

Answer (score 1):

**What worked**: I did suspect that MySQL connection didn't implement the MySql reader as nicely as they should have, but I wasn't sure. After **Evegeny's** answer I decided to do a deeper checked. So I installed the demo version of that awesome software reflector pro and drilled right into the source code of the MySQL Data Connector and it indeed is a bug in MySQL Data connector.

Get rid of the MySQL Helper for getting MySqlDataReader objects and things will be cool again.

Thanks Evgeny.

More Details [here](http://cyrilgupta.com/?p=461)